# How to check if the specified NAV2 behavior tree is running correctly?

Tags: ros2, turtlebot, ros-humble, tutorial, nav2

I am following the [navigation2_dynamic_point_following](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_dynamic_point_following.html) tutorial on ROS 2 Humble. I have executed successfully all the part, but I can not understand if the [follow_point bt](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bt_navigator/behavior_trees/follow_point.xml) is running...
To launch the example I use this two command:
TERMINAL 1:

```
ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py use_sim_time:=False headless:=False autostart:=True default_bt_xml_filename:=/home/ctrazzi/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_bt_navigator/behavior_trees/follow_point.xml
```

I can not past the output since is to much long, so I made some printscreen.

[image: part 1]
[image: part 2]
[image: part 3]
TERMINAL2:

```
   ros2 run nav2_test_utils clicked_point_to_pose
```

I get no output from this node.

If I set the goal with *Nav2 Goal* RViz command the robot behavior is correct, but If I set a new point with *Publish Point* (when the robot is already moving to the previous goal) the robot ignores it and I can not see any message in the terminal.
If I perfom:

```
ros2 topic echo /clicked_point
```

I see the new point value, same if I visualize it in RViz.
If I use rqt_graph I see that the topic of the clicked_point_to_pose node, is not connected to the Nav2 nodes:
[image: rqt_graph]

I think that the behaviour tree is not running, because if I watch the video sample on the tutorial page the robot change path to reach the new point(like the tutorial name says).
[image: Behaviour]

How can I make the BT work?
The [nav2_params.yaml](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/humble/nav2_bringup/params/nav2_params.yaml) is the default of Humble branch: